# "Cannot cast TextView to ToggleButton", but it is a ToggleButton

Tags: android, textview, togglebutton

I am very new to Android development, so I appologise in advance if this is a "noobish" question.

Using a RelativeLayout, I have a ToggleButton with an ID of `reminderToggle`:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/reminderToggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/reminderDesc"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/reminderDesc"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />
```

I am using:

```
ToggleButton reminderToggle = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.reminderToggle);
```

then later:

```
if(reminderToggle.isChecked()) {
```

inside a button `onClick` listener, inside of `onCreate`, to see of the ToggleButton is checked. This was all working fine. I don't know what I did, but now the app crashes when the button is clicked. In LogCat`, I can see

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ToggleButton
at nz.co.kwiius.park.ParkActivity$4.onClick(ParkActivity.java:139)
```

Line 139 is:

```
ToggleButton reminderToggle = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.reminderToggle);
```

As you can see in the XML, reminderToggle is a ToggleButton. So what's all this fuss about? :)

Thanks in advance,
JJ56

PS: There is only one thing with id of reminderToggle, which is this ToggleButton

Comment: Post the code of the Activity, this will help us understand the root of the problem only the onCreate() should be fine. Another thing you could try is clean your project, it may still be running the old code and is conflicting somehow.

Comment: Try Cleaning your project and rebuilding.

Comment: Thank you! That worked fine. Could one of you please repost cleaning and rebuilding as an answer, so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clean and rebuild it dude. Also make sure you check build automatically always to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0):

***If you have defined a TextView prior to ToggleButton and both are defined with same id then*** in that case if you try to get the togglebutton tou wil get class cast exception because ***findViewById() will return you the first element defined using the same id in that xml***. In the following XML the first element defined with id reminderToggle is TextView. SO you can't get ToggleButton using that id

```
ToggleButton reminderToggle = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.reminderToggle);// will result you classcast exception for the following xml
```

**XML**

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        android:id="@+id/reminderToggle" />"
    <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/reminderToggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="ToggleButton" />
```